# Is max-width:auto == max-width:100%?

Tags: html, css

Is

```
max-width:auto;
```

equal to

```
max-width: 100%?
```

And if not, what's the difference?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `auto` is not a valid value for `max-width`

Comment: Don't worry, my answer got downvoted too.

Comment: Random downvotes will happen. Don't let it disspirit you. The question body itself is no place for a meta rant.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are not equal. `auto` is not a valid value for `max-width`.

If you're looking for a value that means "there is no upper bound for the width of this element", that value is `none` (see the spec on [`max-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths)).

`none` is not equal to 100% either, however. The value 100% means that an element can only be as wide as the constraints of its containing block at most (see the spec on [the `width` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) for details on percentage widths).

With `none`, you could still cause the element to be wider than its containing block (which would typically result in overflow), e.g. by setting `width: 150%` on the element. With a max width of 100%, that limit would simply take precedence over the 150% setting.

Comment: Also, `none` is different from `100%`.

Comment: As of April 2020, the MDN page for `max-width` does list `auto` as a valid value for `max-width` and `min-width`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Comment: @snowyBunny: Yes, that's what Dai said two months ago.

Comment: As of October 2022, the MDN page listed in earlier comments does **not** list `auto` as a valid value for `max-width` 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)